# Paradox of language: smelly feet and runny nose

Tags: etymology, pejorative-language

How come our nose run and our feet smell? What is the etymology of this paradox phrase?

Comment: What's the paradox? Are you familiar with the concept of metaphor? And did you know that _smell_ can mean either 'produce a smell' or 'notice a smell'?

Comment: It's a joke. Goodness only knows where or when old jokes started,

Answer (score 4):

There isn't one. Smelly feet/feet smell refers to the odour or scent given off by the feet:

> [smell](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/182542), v.
>
> 8. a. intr. To give out, send forth, or exhale an odour; to have a smell, scent, etc.

A runny nose uses the following definition of runny:

> [runny](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/168945), adj.
>
> 1. a. Tending to run or flow; having the consistency of liquid, fluid, not set; soft, melting; watery.
> 2. orig. U.S. Of the nose: running, discharging mucus. Of the eyes: watering, or tending to water.

Comment: I would argue that runny in this context refers to [definition 4.4](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/run): *To emit or exude liquid.* (I don't have access to the oed to check if this definition is in your dictionary as well)

Comment: @scohe001 the OED is online (click the words themselves for the links) and I think you may be correct, so I'll change it. Thanks.

Comment: It's online if you have an account for it...

Comment: @scohe001 That's odd; I can use the links and I don't have an account (for e.g., the runny one: http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/168945).

Comment: @Blubberguy22 Are you perchance sitting in a library or an academic institution of higher learning?

Comment: @DRF Oh, yes, lol.

Comment: Reason for downvote? The answer is correct.

Comment: I'd like to ask the same question...but users love down voting!!

Answer (score 0):

No paradox, just ordinary language I'd say:

[Runny](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/runny):

> - more liquid than usual:
>     *The sauce looked runny so I added some more flour.*
> - If your nose is runny, it is producing more mucus than usual, usually because you are ill:
>     I've got a runny nose.

[Smell](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/smell):

> - (intr. ) to emit an unpleasant odour; stink