# Why do we say that our nose "runs"?

Tags: american-english

I find it odd that we say our "nose runs". Even stranger is that our feet "smell". Why is this?

Comment: Because nasal mucous is liquid and idiomatically liquids run (i.e., flow)?   Because smell means to emit an odor as well as perceive one?

Comment: _Smell_ is a [sense verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299); they do things like that. As for liquid running, think about "running water" as opposed to "still water". Which one is better to describe mucus flow?

Comment: I think the OP is asking why parts of the body are said to do these actions. When we have a cold, our noses don't literally "run" (away), and our feet cannot "smell" odours, it's our noses that perform this function. Why don't we say our eyes "run" when tears flow from them? We don't, we have a verb that describes the action: cry.

Comment: We say: *My nose is runny*.... *I have a runny nose*, ... *her nose is running*, ... *he suffers from rhinitis*. We don't normally say: *my/your/his (etc) nose runs*

Comment: I think OP question is very clear, what Mari -Lou suggests is interesting but would require a new different question.

Comment: If someone where to answer your question, as it is posed they could just say: *I don't know why zzg finds it strange, why don't you tell us?* And I think you should explain "what" exactly you find strange? The fact that feet are smelly? That feet emit odours? Or that the expression "our feet smell" appears as if they had the actual ability of smell.

Comment: @Josh61 you didn't answer "why" feet smell.

Comment: Make a question! OP was just interested in the 'running nose' :)

Comment: I thought I remembered this question, and I was right! Related: [Paradox of language: smelly feet and runny nose](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/259747/paradox-of-language-smelly-feet-and-runny-nose)

Comment: Sorry for my lack of response. You're correct, @Mari-LouA, in that I was stuck on the "paradox of language".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***"[Runny nose](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/runny-nose-and-running-nose)" vs "running nose":*** (M-W)

> - Both terms are correct, *but runny nose is much more common.*
>     Runny nose is the idiom that Americans use to describe what happens when your nose runs (that is, when liquid comes out of your nose because of a cold, allergy, or crying). This is the term for the general condition of having a running nose and is used in a sentence like the word cold when it refers to an illness.
>     Note also that the idiom is to have a runny nose:
>
>   - *My daughter has cough and a runny nose.*
>   - *Symptoms include runny nose, itchy eyes, and scratchy throat.*
>   - *I wish I could do something about my runny nose.*
> - Running nose has the same meaning but is used only to refer to a specific instance of this symptom, in contrast to the condition in general. This expression is used very rarely; it's literal and descriptive and can be understood as being too direct a reference to something that is unpleasant:
>
>   - *My uncle wiped his running nose with his sleeve.*
>   - *Her baby has a perpetually running nose and a rash on his stomach.*
>   - *Go give that boy with the running nose a kleenex.*

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=runny%20nose%3Aeng_us_2012%2Crunny%20nose%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crunny%20nose%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crunny%20nose%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) (*runny nose AmE vs BrE*). The term is relatively recent (from the 30's according to Google books) and it is actually a more common expression in AmE.

The expression comes from the natural perception of mucus flowing (running) down your nose and as a matter of fact its official scientific definition is:

> - ***Rhinorrhea or rhinorrhoea*** is a condition where the nasal cavity is filled with a significant amount of mucus fluid. The condition, commonly known as a runny nose, occurs relatively frequently.
> - The term was coined in 1866 and is a combination of the Greek terms rhino- ***("of the nose") and -rhoia ("discharge" or "flow").***

(Wikipedia)

Comment: See my comment under the OP's question. I think he needs to first clarify the question.

Comment: Well, you are actually asking another (interesting) question. Do I not answer his?

Comment: Learned a lot from your answer.

Comment: I'm gonna give you the check just because I learned so much more than necessary about runny noses and smelly feet. :-) Though, it was the "paradox of language" that I was stuck on.